# TypeScript include non .ts files in compilation directive

Tags: typescript

For some reason only .ts files are included:

```
{
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "commonjs",
            "target": "es6",
            "noImplicitAny": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "outDir": "dist",
            "baseUrl": ".",
            "types": ["node", "mocha"],
            "paths": {
                "*": [ "src/main/*", "generated/*" ]
            }
        },
        "include": [
            "**/*.yaml"
        ],
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "dist",
            "build"
        ],
        "compileOnSave": false
    }
```

Why is it not picking up the yaml files? They are needed for my Swagger API spec.

Comment: What do you want it to do with those `*.yaml` files?

Comment: @haim770 I want to copy them in my /dist folder so Swagger can read the yaml files and build my API

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `include` is telling the TypeScript compiler what files to compile, not what files it should include in the final bundle.

In other words, you're telling `tsc` what files to "include" in the input to its compilation process.

To include anything other than `.ts`, `.tsx` or `.d.ts` files in your output, seems you need to use a build tool like gulp or webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this issue has been fixed by [@bencergazda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111787/bencergazda) as he has created [typescript-cp](https://github.com/body-builder/typescript-cp) that works exactly like you would have hoped.

It even works in parallel with typescript and requires no real configuration as it reads your tsconfig.

I installed it globally on my machine as it [is available on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-cp) and just ran "tsc" to do the initial copy build, then I add script with "tsc -w && tscp -w" to have typescript work in parallel with typescript-cp.